# React-bootstrap-daterangepicker with input behaves weirdly

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I'm trying to use [react-bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker) with inputs inside of it, and I ran into an unpleasant bug: each time I click on one of the inputs or press any key, calendar is toggled (shown if it was hidden and vice versa). I reproduced it on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/4zx1l0n6p4 You can also see the versions of the dependencies I'm using there.
I'm not sure if the problem is in the package or in my code, so I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: seems to be a plugin bug, https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/190 the owner of this plugin never replied to input questions.

Comment: you were right, I found it eventually! it was satisfying, but I'll probably have to use another plugin in the end :)

Answer (score 1):

Update: I managed to get it to work by installing version 3.4.0 and replacing two inputs with single input: https://codesandbox.io/s/kwy30z9rl3.
The bug I described is probably caused by the addition of the wrapper div in one of the later versions. In the latest version react-bootstrap-daterangepicker wraps any children you pass to it into a container:

```
render() {
const { children, containerStyles, containerClass } = this.props;
return (
  <div
    ref={picker => {
      this.$picker = $(picker);
    }}
    className={containerClass}
    style={containerStyles}
  >
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

}

And bootstrap-daterangepicker checks if the parent of the datepicker is an input/button and apllies the necessary event handlers:

```
if (this.element.is('input') || this.element.is('button')) {
this.element.on({
    'click.daterangepicker': $.proxy(this.show, this),
    'focus.daterangepicker': $.proxy(this.show, this),
    'keyup.daterangepicker': $.proxy(this.elementChanged, this),
    'keydown.daterangepicker': $.proxy(this.keydown, this) //IE 11 compatibility
});
} else {
    this.element.on('click.daterangepicker', $.proxy(this.toggle, this));
    this.element.on('keydown.daterangepicker', $.proxy(this.toggle, this));
}
```

And since the element in question is a plain div, every click or keypress on the input triggers toggle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update you code to like this and need to add the handler in date-picker to handle the change when you select dates. I've added **handelEvent** method to your code.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import DateRangePicker from "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker";
// you will need the css that comes with bootstrap@3. if you are using
// a tool like webpack, you can do the following:
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
// you will also need the css that comes with bootstrap-daterangepicker
import "bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputStart: "01/01/2018",
      inputFinish: "02/01/2018"
    };
    this.handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this);
  }
  handleChangeS = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({ inputStart: event.target.value });
  };
  handleChangeF = event => {
    this.setState({ inputFinish: event.target.value });
  };

  handleEvent(event, picker) {
    this.setState({
      inputStart: picker.startDate,
      inputFinish: picker.endDate
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
        <DateRangePicker
          autoApply={true}
          autoUpdateInput={false}
          startDate={this.state.inputStart}
          endDate={this.state.inputFinish}
          locale={{ format: "DD/MM/YYYY" }}
          onEvent={this.handleEvent}
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.inputStart}
            onChange={this.handleChangeS}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.inputFinish}
            onChange={this.handleChangeF}
          />
        </DateRangePicker>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thanks, but, unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem, I updated my codesandbox, so you can see it: https://codesandbox.io/s/kwy30z9rl3

Comment: Could you please elaborate some thing more that what is the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: Sure! If you open my sandbox and try to type something in one of the inputs, or just move the cursor with arrow keys, the calendar will show/hide on each keypress, and it's not supposed to be that way. It's supposed to behave more like this: http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples

Comment: I think I got your problem, you need to remove autoApply and need to updated onEvent by 'onApply={this.handleEvent}'. After that when you click on date it will not toggle the datepicker.

Comment: autoApply option only controls this: "Hide the apply and cancel buttons, and automatically apply a new date range as soon as two dates are clicked.", so it doesn't really matter, but I changed everything as you suggested and it still doesn't work.
(also, there is an option on codesandbox to fork a sandbox and edit it yourself, so feel free to play with my code, if you'd like :))

Comment: yes, you are right that it will only hide the apply and cancel but if you use the autoApply then if you click on single date twice it will select that date for both the inputs and the datepicker will toggled.